# VS2013 missing pending changes in project tab

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have visual studio premium 2013 , and recently all the buttons on the project tab have disappeared, no MyWork button pending changes button etc..

I'm still connected to my team server and can open these option via the menu options .

how can I restore the  buttons to the project tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research , what worked for me . is from an admin command prompt 
running the following command

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /setup